# romper cache view true ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, cache

Cargo los productos en este controlador...

```
.controller('productosCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q, $location, $ionicLoading, Productos) {
    Productos.productos().then(function(argument, $timeout) {
        console.log(argument)
        $scope.tiendaD = {
            nameS: argument.store.name,
            addressS: argument.store.address,
            idS: argument.store.id,
            logoS: argument.store.logo.logo.url
        };
        $scope.producto = []
        for (var i = 0; i <= argument.store.products.length - 1; i++) {
            $scope.producto.push({
                id: argument.store.products[i].id,
                name: argument.store.products[i].name,
                description: argument.store.products[i].description,
                category: argument.store.products[i].category,
                store: argument.store.products[i].store,
                price: argument.store.products[i].price,
                picture: argument.store.products[i].picture.picture.url
            });

        }
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    })
})
```

Mi factory

```
.factory('Productos', function($q, $http, $location) {
    var Api = {};
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    Api.productos = function() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var paramId = $location.search().id;
        var urlaux = "http://abbie-core.herokuapp.com/api/stores/" + paramId + "?token=" + localStorage.getItem('token') + "&user_id=" + localStorage.getItem('user_id');
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: urlaux,
        }).success(function(data) {
            defer.resolve(data);
        })
        return defer.promise;
    }
    return Api;
})
```

... y los imprimo en la vista con un *ng repeat*, a la vista donde imprimo estos productos le coloco `cache view true`, pero si agrego un nuevo producto y salgo, y entro a la vista, no puedo ver el otro producto tengo que recargar la vista.

¿Que puedo hacer para romper ese *cache* cuando hay un nuevo producto?

Comment: retorna directamente la promesa directamente usando `return $http(....`. Lo que tienes con `var defer = $q.defer` y `return defer.promise` se conoce como el [antipatrón de construcción explicita](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

El error es que nunca los guardas donde debes guarlos.. Tu al guardar un nuevo producto lo guardas en `$scope.producto` pero cuando vuelve a entrar a tu controlador recorres `Productos.productos()`, me imagino que tienes algun factory que obtiene los productos y tambien los guarda que se llama Productos.

Voy a dejar un codigo, no me puse 100% en tu contexto pero creo que aqui radica el error

```
.factory('Productos', function() {
    productos = [];
    return {
         productos: function(){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var paramId = $location.search().id;
            var urlaux = "http://abbie-core.herokuapp.com/api/stores/" + paramId + "?token=" + localStorage.getItem('token') + "&user_id=" + localStorage.getItem('user_id');
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: urlaux,
            }).success(function(data) {
                defer.resolve(data);
            })
            return defer.promise;
         }, 
         add : function(producto){
             //Llamar a funcion que agrega en tu API los productos
         }
         ....
    }
 )}
```

Para agregarlo desde

```
for (var i = 0; i <= argument.store.products.length - 1; i++) {
        var produ = {
            id: argument.store.products[i].id,
            name: argument.store.products[i].name,
            description: argument.store.products[i].description,
            category: argument.store.products[i].category,
            store: argument.store.products[i].store,
            price: argument.store.products[i].price,
            picture: argument.store.products[i].picture.picture.url
        }
        Producto.add(produ);
 }
 $scope.producto = Producto.productos();
```

**EDIT**

Ahora que publicas tu `factory`, me doy cuenta que siempre que quieres ver tus productos haces un llamado a tu `API` y los devuelves, EN ESTE CASO lo que debes hacer es crear en tu `API` una funcion que reciba un nuevo producto y lo agregue. Eso hará que cada vez que agregues uno nuevo se muestre ya que tus productos son siempre desde tu `API`.